# Too many views in activity

Tags: android, memory, android-activity

I have an activity with more then 200 diffident views and layouts. Some of the views are images and some are texts or buttons. The visibility of the views changes from time to time, and so some of the textView contents, but nothing more.

The problem is with devices with big screens when the activity is out of focus and gets deleted from the stuck (see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html) under "Saving activity state" section). Unfortunately, to restore it with onRestoreInstanceState() , is a real mess.

I was wondering maybe I should not use Views but implement it in a different way in order to save memory?
Maybe just bitmap images on a Canvas or something else?

Any suggestion tricks, tips will be appreciated.

Comment: "I have an activity with more then 200 diffident views and layouts". don't you think that may be a bit too much ?

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you to use Fragments, if you have a lot of views and layouts in one activity.

Answer (score 0):

you can use any number of views as layout, you saying that it will change depends on time,

```
use setVisibility(View.Visible)
setVisibility(View.GONE)
setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
```

Comment: The implementation is fine, my intention is memory saving.